# Is translation of certificates for professorship positions required?

Tags: united-states, job-search, tenure-track, assistant-professor, translations

The job websites of some US universities ask to upload a doctoral certificate for assistant professor positions in Computer Science.  My doctoral certificate is not in English. IMHO, a quick look on it suffices to read my name and "doktor rerum naturalium" to convince oneself that I indeed have a PhD. Still, no website mentions that a certificate should be in English.  As a rule of thumb, without asking, should I

- continue uploading my current foreign-language certificate, or
- get my certificate translated by a sworn translator, or
- self-translate my certificate?

Comment: The answer to your question depends upon the specific university you are applying to.

Comment: The default expectation is that you ask.

Answer (score 4):

Some US diplomas aren’t in English, either! So just upload what you have, or if you have particular concerns, you can contact whoever’s listed in the ad to answer.

Generally, such formal documentation is required at the time of the formal offer or at the hire, not for the initial application.

Comment: @Abra Some diplomas are still written in Latin.  For example, [Princeton provides translations of the Latin in their diplomas](https://registrar.princeton.edu/student-services/translations-of-diplomas/), which presumably indicates the diplomas are still in Latin.

Comment: @Abra: A school's diplomas will all be in the same language, regardless of department. So, yes, there are reputable schools in the US with PhD diplomas in a foreign language.

Comment: Diplomas in Latin. Wow. Even though the university was founded several decades after Latin ceased to be used by anyone other than catholic priests seriously.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Newton’s _Principia_ were published exclusively in Latin in the 1680s, and an English translation didn’t appear until 1728! Knowledge of Latin was also considered an essential part of a good education at the time.

Comment: I simply find the idea that a university delivering diplomas in a language from another continent and several centuries ago rather... pompous.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Graduation is all about pomp  (and circumstance).